# Fundamental theorem of calculus - increasing function

Tags: calculus

Suppose that a function $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b fg=0$ for any continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$. Prove that $f(x)=0$ for any $x \in [a,b]$.

Suppose that a function $d$ is continuous and increasing on the interval $[0,\infty]$. Prove that $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x} \int_0^x d$ also increases on $[0, \infty]$.

I am not sure how to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus here.

Comment: Please verify that my edits preserve the meaning and intent of your question.

Comment: A continious function on a closed interval takes a maximal avlue on this interval. So $|f(x)| \leq M \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and the same goes for the function $g$. Then try to do integration by parts on $\int_a^b fg dx$. This would help you further.

Comment: Yes your edits are correct. So the. I have the integral = gF - int(Fg'dx) =0 so gF=Int(Fg'dx) but what does that tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the first problem, we can take $g(x)=f(x), \;\;\forall x\in [a,b].$
Suppose that $(\exists x_0\in[a,\ b]):\;\;  f(x_0)\ne{0}.$ Then from continuity of $f\;\;$ there exists a neighbourhood $U(x_0)$ such that $(\forall x\in U(x_0))\;\; f^2(x)>0, \;\; $ therefore,  $\int\limits_{a}^{b}{f^2(x)\ dx>0}.$ Contradiction.

Comment: What are you assuming here?

Comment: Assuming that $f\not\equiv{0}$ on $[a,\ b].$

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't require the fundamental theorem, just let $g=f$, which implies $\int_a^b f^2 = 0$, so that $f=0$ on $[a,b]$. As for a hint on why $\int f^2=0$ implies $f=0$, use the continuity of $f$ to show that if $f$ is nonzero somewhere, it is nonzero on a neighborhood, which makes $\int f^2$ strictly positive.

Edit: For the second part, you want to show that $g'>0$. So $g'(x)= \frac{-1}{x^2} \int_0^x d + d(x)\frac{1}{x}$, where I used FTC in the first term. Factor as $g'(x)= \frac{1}{x} \left( d(x) - \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x d \right)$. We need this to be positive, so we need $d(x) > \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x d$. However, notice that the RHS of the inequality is the average value of $d$ on $(0,x)$, which is going to be smaller than the value of $d$ at $x$ since $d$ is strictly increasing. So the inequality holds, so $g'(x) > 0$ on $(0, \infty)$, so $g$ is increasing as you want.

Comment: Do I need to use FTC in the second problem?